# Number of SSH connection(s) on a single linux machine

Tags: ssh, limit

I landed up in a situation wherein I had to access a Linux machine via puTTY.I made various attempts to SSH but failed to connect to the machine.
I then realised my colleague was accessing the same Linux machine as root user,and I too wanted to access as a root user.I asked him to log out so that I can login as root.
Is there a way we limit number of SSH login on a linux OS? Is this some kind of security feature that distinguishes a windows based OS with a linux based OS.

Comment: Are you saying that you could login as root once he logged out? And you want to know how or where this limit might be set?

Comment: yes i am able to login as root once he logged out

Answer (score 10):

You probably have limits set in `/etc/security/limits.conf` like so

```
root hard maxlogins 1
```

Change the limit (1) to something higher if needed.

Comment: This setting does not affect concurrent SSH logins on Centos6

Comment: This is a limit PAM would look up. If you allow root login via ssh keys then...

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is possible to limit the number of concurrent login sessions, although most Linux distributions do not impose such limits in their default settings.

Linux is proper multi-user system by design and normally you shouldn't have any problems with having multiple concurrent SSH sessions for the same user.

The SSH server can impose such limits with the `MaxSessions` option in the configuration file. Through PAM you can impose such limits as well as others have already pointed out.

Comment: I am using Cent OS 6.4. Does it limit concurrent SSH sessions ?

Comment: Not by default.

Answer (score 6):

Trying to convince a standalone `sshd` daemon to limit the number of sessions is fraught with loopholes.  Things like `MaxSessions` limit something other than what the OP is talking about.  And `sshd` ignores `limits.conf` on linux (similarly `login.conf` on FreeBSD) unless you configure things properly to route all incoming sessions through PAM and use the appropriately configured PAM module to check things like limits.conf first.  It's hard to get it working right.

On the other hand, if you don't start `sshd` as a standalone daemon, then you can use the limiting features in the "thing" that spawns `sshd` on demand.

For instance, `inetd` and `xinetd` have a connection limiting feature (that usually defaults to not enforcing any limit to the number of forked children).  In classic `inetd`, it's called "max-child".  With `xinetd`, look for the `instances` configuration knob.  For example, `inetd` style:

```
ssh  stream  tcp  nowait/3  root  /usr/sbin/sshd  sshd -i -4
```

That limits the number of concurrent ssh connections to 3.

For those who are so inclined, `systemd` can replace the function of `inetd`, and I believe there is a way to limit the number of instances of a service.  Exercise left to the reader (or add a comment with the details!).

Comment: `systemd` users will want to look at `systemctl show sshd.socket | grep -i maxcon` and `man systemd.socket`.