# ssh + what is the default count of parallel ssh session to rhel machine that machine can allow in the same time

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel, sshd

We have 736 [RHEL](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) machines that sometimes access the central server via ssh. In the worst-case, all machines can be connected to the one server at the same time.

Is there any restriction on how many ssh connections can be established at the same time?

I can see that in `sshd_config` I have `#MaxSessions 10` but this parameter is disabled, so what is the default setting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of SSH connection(s) on a single linux machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127077/number-of-ssh-connections-on-a-single-linux-machine) . There should not be any except if you set one, however the machine's resources might see quite a load.

Comment: we have rhel server and the conf is diff

Comment: limit can be number of process (if ssh to a non-root account), number of open file, or general overload (whatever that mean) of hosts. By the way `MaxSession` refer to session multipexing (like bitwise windows client using one connexion for both shell and sft for instance)